# dynamically changing the url in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a shopping cart web in react .
here is a single product page

```
import React from "react";
import "./Clothes.css";
import data from "../../JSON/JsonData.json";
import Sproduct from "../Sproduct";

const SweaterMen = ({cart,setCart}) => {

 return (
   <>
     <div className="imageCard">
     {data.map(prod => {
       return <Sproduct prod={prod} cart={cart} setCart={setCart} />
     })}
     </div>

   </>

);
};


export default SweaterMen;
```

** this is a product file ,  there are multiple files like this in my project **

**Sproduct.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Sproduct = ({ prod, cart, setCart }) => {
  return (
    <div className="imageOuterCard">
      <img
        onClick={() => {
          setCart([...cart, prod]);
        }}
        src={prod.url}
        alt="product"
      />
      <p>ID:-{prod.id}</p>
      <p>Description:{prod.desc}</p>
      <p>PRICE:-{prod.price}</p>
    </div>
  );
};




export default Sproduct;
```

** the cart and setCart state are coming from the main home page **

**JsonData.json**

```
[
  
  {
    "case":"",
    "id": "1",
    "name": "xyz",
    "url": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81p6ytlGM2L._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "trackPants": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51yQ0QnV8RL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "trackSuits": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61dzZlbr3RL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "tShirt": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71yfuOrfnBL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "short":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71TNu2SUUFL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "kurtas":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41Vfg7cHa9L._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "sherwani":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61sz1pj0WbL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "shoes":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71ag3ysSzML._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "ss":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51fYig8OYIL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg", 
    "price": "21",
    "desc": "Sweet & Comfy"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "xyz",
    "url": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91q9wOMyL+L._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "trackPants": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/716fx0Ld+mL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "trackSuits": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61RndDenb6L._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "tShirt": " https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71T2xhso8OL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "short":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81HujMLZAwL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "kurtas":" https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/31SLw4vvLXL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "sherwani":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71w21lwmtXL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "shoes":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/610fN3RyKFL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "ss":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71H0VCiuJyL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg", 
    "price": "21",
    "desc": "Sweet & Comfy"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "xyz",
    "url": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/816dntXaVuL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "trackPants": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61ATxsMYpkL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "trackSuits": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61kkRuK8tsL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "tShirt": " https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61Mj4YKDYJL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "short":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51Gw2wxUJlS._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "kurtas":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41YZzFCHvKL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "sherwani":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61B5J229muL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "ss":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51EeHo8CDsL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg", 
    "shoes":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61utX8kBDlL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
    "price": "21",
    "desc": "Sweet & Comfy"
  }
  
]
```

now , there is a `src={prod.url}` line in Sproduct file , the url is the link of image inside the *JsonData.json*
*I want to change that url dynamically into shoes, sherwani .... etc  *
how to do that please help..

Comment: Can you determine the type of product i.e if the product is a shoe or tracksuit?

Comment: @saim2025 the url consist of all sweater , and the rest are in json file , i want to chnage the url to "trackpants" when the trackpants element is clicked